# scraping search results page in amazon using Jsoup

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to scrape two urls:

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=pendrives&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Apendrives

http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=FDW+CLEAR+SPRINGS+125+GMS

In the first url, I am searching for **pendrives** and I am getting results which are nested under "atfresults" tag , which I have been able to scrape.

whereas for second url  I am searching for **FDW CLEAR SPRINGS 125 GMS** for which I get "Your search **FDW CLEAR SPRINGS 125 GMS** did not match any products." but it does return three products in "searchTemplate", which I am unable to traverse through using Jsoup. I need help in finding the description of those 3 products

Answer (score 3):

You can find them using:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36")
                .maxBodySize(0)
                .get();
Elements products = doc.select(".s-result-list-parent-container > ul > li");
```

Or you can directly find the description using:

```
Elements products = doc.select(".s-result-list-parent-container > ul > li .s-access-title");
```

Comment: sorry, can u please mention any solution for second link in above question. your solution does work for first url and I also have already done extraction for the first link. My question was how to extract in second link and not in first link.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, its working on try.jsoup.org and then I realised it was using "user agent" while connecting . I too then used user agent and its working from my eclipse IDE also.

Comment: may be the site was using some script to print the content and that is why "user agent" should be mentioned so that the script is first run using the "user agent" and then the html is extracted so that it contains complete content of the page

Comment: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/287   you can follow this thread to know more about this issue

Comment: @sujit I've added the user agent and the max body size in my answer.

Comment: any suggestions on how to work on this website [link](https://paytm.com/shop/search/?q=fiama%20di%20wills%20%20clear%20springs&from=organic)  even jsoup.org nor using user agent is not enough for this

Comment: Can you please create another question for this link?